Which method of laser diode operation is less likely to cause mode hopping: constant current or constant power?
If a laser diode is uncolled and operates in a CW mode then which method of operation is less likely to cause mode hopping: constant current or constant power?

This might be a good place to start looking for answers - https://www.rp-photonics.com/mode_hopping.html
